# Сравнение списков разной длинны

Tags: java, android, сортировка

Здравствуйте!

Никак не могу придумать алгоритм, с помощью которого можно решить проблему:

Есть большой список операций, у каждого объекта есть несколько полей, из которых формируется другая сущность `Контрагент`.

В чем загвоздка?

Нужно взять список операций, вынуть из них контрагентов, и хранить, но  операций много, контрагенты часто повторяются, и мне не нужно чтобы они дублировались в таблице списка контрагентов.
В случае, если мы встречаем одного и того же контрагента, мы должны сохранять только контрагента из последней операции (есть поле соответсвующее).

Каким путём пойти?

Использовать `HashSet` и переопределять метод `hashCode()` ?

Переопределить компаратор и метод `equals()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, `HashSet` подойдет, только переопределять нужно и `hashCode()` и `equals()`, причем таким образом чтобы поле которое описывает с какой он операции не учитывалось.

Далее алгоритм простой: 
Если контрагента нет в HashSet, добавляем, если есть и у нового новее операция заменяем на нового.